# Looping and taking values out

Tags: python

[image]

```
lists = [[100.0,90.0],[52.0,75.0,45.0,20.0],[12.0,43.0,55.0]]
def printAverages(lists):
    for values in lists:
        print(values)
        row(values)



def row(values):
    num = 0
    for numbers in values:
        if numbers == min(values):
            values.remove(numbers)
        else:
            num += numbers
    print(num)
```

It out puts the following,

```
[100.0, 90.0]

100.0

[52.0, 75.0, 45.0, 20.0]

172.0

[12.0, 43.0, 55.0]

55.0
```

I'm trying to remove the smallest value and add the rest of the values together, but it seems i'm just way off. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the expected output? Also, it is not a good idea to modify the list you're looping through.

Comment: The output is supposed to be the average of each individual nested list, excluding the lowest number. I just for the life of me can't figure it out. Where was i modifying it at?

Comment: Anyone willing to take a look? been stuck for hours

Comment: I agree w/ Railslide "it is not a good idea to modify the list you're looping through"

Comment: How can i approach this differently?

Comment: You could get the sum of the whole list with just `sum(values)`, and then you can get the min with just `min(values)`, so why not just `sum(values) - min(values)` that way you're never actually altering the list, so you don't have to worry about any of that. If you want to get the list of scores excluding the lowest score, another solution might be `sorted(values)[1:]` which will create a *new* list, containing all the scores in order, excluding the first (`0`-th) score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Average = Sum of observations / Total number of observations. That's where you were wrong.

Also I removed the if part where you remove the smallest number from the list from the code. Why would you? It's not required in this case.

**EDIT**: I added an example from the image you posted just to verify that this code if correct.

```
lists = [[100.0,90.0],[52.0,75.0,45.0,20.0],[12.0,43.0,55.0],[80.0, 75.0, 70.0, 65.0, 5.0]]
def printAverages(lists):
    for values in lists:
        print(values)
        row(values)

def row(values):
    num = 0
    observations = 0
    for number in values:
        if number != min(values):
            num += number
            observations += 1
    print(num / observations)

printAverages(lists)
```

The result of the last list `[80.0, 75.0, 70.0, 65.0, 5.0]` (which is copied from the image you gave) is `72.5` - as in the image.

---

If you want to remove the smallest value from the list anyway and then print the list without that smallest value then you have to move the `print` command from the function `printAverages(lists)` to the function `row(values)`

The code would be something like this:

```
lists = [[100.0,90.0],[52.0,75.0,45.0,20.0],[12.0,43.0,55.0],[80.0, 75.0, 70.0, 65.0, 5.0]]
def printAverages(lists):
    for values in lists:
        row(values)

def row(values):
    num = 0
    observations = 0
    for number in values:
        if number == min(values):
            values.remove(number)
        else:
            num += number
            observations += 1
    print values
    print(num / observations)

printAverages(lists)
```

Comment: I was approaching this the opposite way instead of removing it you used the !=. Thanks so much. I've been at this for a while. That print command was just to make sure it was going correctly, but anyways thanks so much